# Use touch command to set modification time of a file to the Unix epoch

Tags: linux, date, touch

Edit: Better worded question: How do I only use the touch command to set the modification time of a file to the unix epoch?

I know that the unix epoch value can be retrieved using "data %s", but how do I use the touch command (and only that command) to set the modification time to the unix epoch?

Edit2:

So, I found that this runs without any errors:

```
touch -m -d ”@$(date +%s)” fileexample.txt
```

Is this a correct way of setting the modification time of a file to the Unix epoch?

---

---

Original Question (disregard)...:

```
Using the Linux manual for the “touch” command, show the command that you would 
use to set the modification time of a file to the Unix epoch.
```

I understand that the Unix epoch is the amount of second (or miliseconds, I forgot) that has passed since the epoch (1970, January, 01)

What does the question mean by saying: setting the time "**to the** Unix epoch"?

So, Is it basically asking for today's time, or 1970 01 01, or...?

I know the command for this would be:

```
touch -m -t time file
```

But what time do I set it to?

Also, am I meant to use the unix epoch format for the time in the command?

Comment: @jsotola Well, I don't understand the question - or maybe I don't know enough about it. I can set it to the current time or to 1st January 1970 using -t 197001010000, but I don't know what I'm actually meant to do and I'm being very stupid right now.

Comment: ?????  `I don't understand the question` ... is this a school assignment?

Comment: @jsotola Not exactly, but it's a question I was set to do in an introductory programme to Linux (There's a bunch of other questions, but I just don't exactly understand or know how to do this one as I'm a beginner in Linux and almost never used it before, and the wording is throwing me off.)

Comment: read your own sentence above, the one starting with `I understand ...` ....... now think, when is unix epoch zero?  ..... when is it 10? .... when is it 20? ......... is this correct ? `1st January 1970 using -t 197001010000`

Comment: @jsotola So, I'm meant to get the value of the Unix epoch (amount of seconds that has passed since 01 January 1970) and use that value in the command? I don't know how to get the Unix epoch value in Linux or how to put it in the touch command

Comment: @jsotola So, I found out that you can get the Unix epoch value using "date +%s", but how do I put that in my touch command, because if I try and use ^ that, or +%s it says that I am using an invalid date format?

Comment: @jsotola Ok, so I managed to figure something out and this command runs without errors: touch -m -d ”@$(date +%s)” file. Is this correctly setting the modification time to the unix epoch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-t` doesn't accept epoch time, `-d` does

```
   -d, --date=STRING
          parse STRING and use it instead of current time

   -t STAMP
          use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
```

You need to use `-d` or `--date` instead of `-t` and you need to put `@` before epochtime format is used, as described in `date` manpages:

```
   EXAMPLES
       Convert seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 UTC) to a date

              $ date --date='@2147483647'
```

Example:

```
touch --date=@1442968132 test.txt
```

If you want to change modify time only, use `-m` or `--time modify` or `--time mtime`, without it both modify and access times are changed.

```
   -m     change only the modification time

   --time=WORD
          change the specified time: WORD is access, atime, or use: equivalent to -a WORD is modify or mtime: equivalent to -m
```

Examples:

```
$ touch --date=@1442968132 test
$ stat test
  File: test
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 43266017    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    user1)   Gid: ( 1000/    user1)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2015-09-23 02:28:52.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2015-09-23 02:28:52.000000000 +0200
Change: 2018-11-23 11:34:59.893888360 +0100
 Birth: -

$ touch --date=@1542968132 test
$ stat test
  File: test
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 43266017    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    user1)   Gid: ( 1000/    user1)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2018-11-23 11:15:32.000000000 +0100
Modify: 2018-11-23 11:15:32.000000000 +0100
Change: 2018-11-23 11:35:06.893888073 +0100
Birth: -

$ touch -m --date=@1342968132 test
$ stat test
  File: test
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 43266017    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    user1)   Gid: ( 1000/    user1)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2018-11-23 11:15:32.000000000 +0100
Modify: 2012-07-22 16:42:12.000000000 +0200
Change: 2018-11-23 11:35:22.300887441 +0100
```

Comment: Also, is touch -m -d ”@$(date +%s)” test.txt a correct way of doing it?

Comment: yes if you want to change modify time only, without it it will change access time also